# Pulling a string from Java to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've spent a couple hours on this and can't really find an answer. I'm using ionic to build an Android Web App and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) for sending notifications. Every user gets a token so they can receive a notification. The token gets generated in Java via:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "FCMPlugin";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh(){
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

}
}
```

However I need that token (64 char string) to be somehow passed into my JS file since my user registration is done within it. Has anyone come across something like this?

OR

Get the current devices Firebase token by using Javascript?

Comment: Hi can't you use request or session in your server side part?

Comment: Is it fair to say that you are trying to inject a string originating from Java into a webview to be handled by some javascript?  I don't know ionic, but I suspect you'll need some sort or bridge from Java into Javascript executing in the webview.